# SSRS not showing all data between date range

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

Hello I am using SQL to create a report that shows tranx info between date ranges. But I have an interesting issue and I will illustrate it with the table below

| Press | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | Start | 08/01/2021 |
| AB | QA Check | 08/02/2021 |
| AB | Down | 08/02/2021 |
| AB | Start | 08/03/2021 |
| AB | Break | 08/05/2021 |
| AB | No Data | 08/07/2021 |
| AB | Start | 08/07/2021 |
| AB | End | 08/10/2021 |

I have a code similar to this:

```
Select Press, Status, Date
from Table
where Date >= @Date and Date <= @Date
```

In my Sql developer environment when I put Date >= '08/01/2021' and Date <= '08/05/2021', I will get this:

| Press | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | Start | 08/01/2021 |
| AB | QA Check | 08/02/2021 |
| AB | Down | 08/02/2021 |
| AB | Start | 08/03/2021 |
| AB | Break | 08/05/2021 |

but in my report and SSRS I would get:

| Press | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | Start | 08/01/2021 |
| AB | QA Check | 08/02/2021 |
| AB | Down | 08/02/2021 |
| AB | Start | 08/03/2021 |

As you noticed, in SSRS the **08/05/2021** values did not populate, but in SSRS if I change increase >= by one day *"08/06/2021"*, I will see results that show **08/05/2021** values. Is there something I am doing incorrectly in SSRS?

Comment: Its because of a timestamp.  ```TRUNC``` Date

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of your `Date` column compared to the variable you are passing in? Are they both actually data type `date`, or are you casting/converting one? The following code executes as expected in both SSMS and SSRS (though I am not on 2008).

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (Press VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, Status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, SDate DATE NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES
('AB',  'Start' ,'08/01/2021'),
('AB',  'QA Check', '08/02/2021'),
('AB',  'Down'  ,'08/02/2021'),
('AB',  'Start' ,'08/03/2021'),
('AB',  'Break' ,'08/05/2021'),
('AB',  'No Data',  '08/07/2021'),
('AB',  'Start',    '08/07/2021'),
('AB',  'End'   ,'08/10/2021')

Select Press, Status, SDate
from @t1
where SDate >='08/01/2021' and SDate <= '08/05/2021'
```

And the following loses the 08/05/2021 row, since unspecified the time is 12:00:00 AM:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (Press VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, Status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, SDate DATETIME NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES
('AB',  'Start' ,'08/01/2021 5:00:00 AM'),
('AB',  'QA Check', '08/02/2021 5:00:00 AM'),
('AB',  'Down'  ,'08/02/2021 5:00:00 AM'),
('AB',  'Start' ,'08/03/2021 5:00:00 AM'),
('AB',  'Break' ,'08/05/2021 5:00:00 AM'),
('AB',  'No Data',  '08/07/2021 5:00:00 AM'),
('AB',  'Start',    '08/07/2021 5:00:00 AM'),
('AB',  'End'   ,'08/10/2021 5:00:00 AM')

Select Press, Status, SDate
from @t1
where SDate >='08/01/2021' and SDate <= '08/05/2021'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just cast the `Date` column (which I guess is datetime) to only compare the date part .

```
Select Press, Status, Date
from Table
where CAST([Date] as date) >= @Date and CAST([Date] as date) <= @Date
```

or, if your @Date parameter is only a date then simply

```
Select Press, Status, Date
from Table
where CAST([Date] as date) = CAST(@Date as date)
```